# How to dynamically manage CPU load in netty?

Tags: java, multithreading, netty

afaik, EventLoops are backed by Executors, "children/workers" are backed by EventLoops, "parents/bosses" manage activation of "children/workers" on a channel.

1. Is there a blocking queue somewhere to hold incoming requests until a child is available to handle them?
2. How many threads will a child create?
3. How to ensure that incoming channel events to a parent are rejected in the event that the queue backing the child thread pools is full?

It is difficult to discern where/how netty's underlying thread pools are configured.

I can figure 3 out if someone can provide some detail on 1 & 2.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, a `NioEventLoopGroup` extends `MultithreadEventExecutorGroup` which creates its `EventExecutor[] children` as a `new SingleThreadEventExecutor[nThreads]`. The `TaskQueue` of this `SingleThreadEventExecutor` is a `LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()`.

   http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/concurrent/SingleThreadEventExecutor.html
2. The standard constructor of NioEventLoopGroup() creates the default amount of event loop threads:

   ```
   DEFAULT_EVENT_LOOP_THREADS = Math.max(1, SystemPropertyUtil.getInt(
       "io.netty.eventLoopThreads", Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2));
   ```

   You could pass `io.netty.eventLoopThreads` as a JVM-launch argument.

   You can also enter the amount of threads in the constructor of NioEventLoopGroup(). We use this for example:

   ```
   private final static int BOSS_THREADS = 1;
   private final static int MAX_WORKER_THREADS = 12;
   ```

   ---

   ```
   EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(BOSS_THREADS);
   EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(calculateThreadCount());
   ```

   ---

   ```
   private int calculateThreadCount() {
       int threadCount;
       if ((threadCount = SystemPropertyUtil.getInt("io.netty.eventLoopThreads", 0)) > 0) {
           return threadCount;
       } else {
           threadCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;
           return threadCount > MAX_WORKER_THREADS ? MAX_WORKER_THREADS : threadCount;
       }
   }
   ```
3. I actually don't know if Netty has a built-in function for this. AFAIK the queue just takes `Integer.MAX_VALUE` threads.